# Elementary Probability Questions with conditional clause, at least, exactly,

Tags: probability, combinations

I'm currently preparing for a state exam this Saturday and it involves a few questions on probability (which I haven't seen in 10+ years). I'm a little rusty so please excuse my errors with my practice problems. Here are the problems I'm working on:

$$There \ are \ 12 \ red,\  8 \ blue, \ and \ 5 \ green \ marbles. If \ 2 \ are \ selected \ at \ random, \ what \ is \ the \ probability \ that:$$

A) The second marble is blue given that the first marble is not blue

My approach (using conditional probability): $$\frac {\frac{17}{25}*\frac{8}{24}}{\frac {17}{25}}$$

Not sure if the above is correct though.

B) At least one of them is blue

My approach: $P(at \ least\ one\ is\ blue) = 1-P(None \ of \ the \ two \ are \ blue)$

$$ 1-\frac{_{17}C_2}{_{25}C_2}$$

I'd appreciate hints for the following two:

C) Exactly one of them is blue

D) The first marble selected is red (with replacement) and the second marble selected is blue?

Comment: The answer to A) is (I think clearly) $8/24$. For C) add the probabilities of blue, then not blue and not blue, then blue. (The probabilities are the same).

Comment: To follow up on @AndréNicolas, if you want to use the conditional probability formula in A), then the denominator should be 17/25, since it represents the probability that the first marble isn't blue. This cancels out both 17/25 leaving you with 8/24 = 1/3 .

Comment: @DeoxNa thanks for pointing that out just made an edit.

Comment: @AndréNicolas shouldn't A be 17/24? Given that the first marble is blue means there are 7 blue marbles left. This means that there will be 17 non blue divided by 24...shouldn't my answer be 17/24?

Comment: No it should not. The first is not blue, leaving $8$ blue out of $24$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(A) Given that the first marble is not blue, there are $24$ marbles left, of which $8$ are blue, so the probability that the second marble is blue is then $\frac8{24}=\frac13$.

(B) This is fine.

(C) There are $8$ blue marbles and $17$ non-blue marbles, so there are $8\cdot17$ pairs of marbles containing exactly one blue marble. There are $\binom{25}2$ pairs altogether, so ... ? (I’m assuming here that you’re drawing without replacement. If you’re drawing with replacement, simply split the desired outcome into two cases, blue then not-blue, and not-blue then blue.)

(D) Just multiply the probability that the first is red by the probability that the second is blue, remembering that in both cases you’re drawing from the full pool of $25$ marbles.

Comment: C) 136/300
D) 96/625?

Comment: @User69127: Yes, those look fine.

Comment: shouldn't A be 17/24? Given that the first marble is blue means there are 7 blue marbles left. This means that there will be 17 non blue divided by 24...shouldn't my answer be 17/24?

Comment: @User69127: We’re given that the first marble is **not** blue.

Comment: For C, I believe you meant to say $_{8}C_1 * _{17}C_2$ divided by all pairs together

Comment: @User69127: No, I meant $$\frac{8\cdot17}{\binom{25}2}$$ or, if you insist on using binomial coefficients when choosing only one, $$\frac{\binom81\binom{17}1}{\binom{25}2}\;.$$